# Add CSS for HTML-DIV

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set the CSS-class in javascript for a DIV-element?

```
<div id="myId">
     <!-- -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("myId").className = "someClass";
```

Using jQuery:

```
$("#myId").attr("class", "someClass");
```

Comment: +1 for the corrected post Matt. Yeah my bad my solution was not exact

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("myId").className = "someClass";
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery

```
$("#myId").attr("class", "cssClass");
```

Comment: This *adds* to the class name; it doesn't set it as requested.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, use the native [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method, which is easier to read and purpose built for this exact question

```
$('#myId').addClass('foo');
```

Comment: No, as I said above, this adds a class.  It doesn't set the class name.

Comment: What do you mean? The above jQuery snippet is a setter not a getter, i.e. it will add the class the the elements selected.